# passport Error: Failed to serialize user into session

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have a little problem with passport-local using a mySQL-DB.

I get following error message when i try to login:

> Error: Failed to serialize user into session
>
> at /your/path/to/project/auth.js:11:5

The query seems to be ok. I get the correct object as response.

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    firstname: 'firstname',
    lastname: 'lastname',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password in hash',
    role: 'role',
    enabled: 1 } ]
```

But if i

```
console.log(user)
```

in

```
passport.serializeUser
```

i get a

```
[]
```

Thanks in advance :-)

**The auth.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const userModel = require('./user/model');

module.exports = app => {
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    //console.log(user.id);
    done(null, user.id);
  })
  //passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    userModel.get({ id }).then(
      user => {
        if (!user) {
          done('user not found');
        }
        done(null, user);
      },
      err => done(err),
    );
  });

  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
      
      const hash = crypto
        .createHash('md5')
        .update(password)
        .digest('hex');
        console.log({password: hash});
      userModel.get({ username, password: hash }).then(
        user => {
          if (!user) {
            done('user not found');
          }
          //console.log(user);
          done(null, user);
        },
        error => done('FEHLER: ' + error),
      );
    }),
  );

  app.use(
    expressSession({
      secret: 'geheim',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: {secure: true}
    }),
  );

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  app.post(
    '/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    (request, response) => {
      response.redirect('/');
    },
  );
  app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```

**The model.js**

```
'use strict';
const dbServerConnection = require('../controller/mysqlconnector.js');

function get(query = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let queryElements = [];
      if (query) {
        for (let key in query) {
          queryElements.push(`${key} = ?`);
        }
      }
  
      const queryString =
        'SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE ' + queryElements.join(' AND ');
      dbServerConnection.query(queryString, Object.values(query), (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
  module.exports = {
    get,
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Your `RowDataPacket` is not normal object, so I guess you need to change code

```
dbServerConnection.query(queryString, Object.values(query), (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          console.log(results);
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
```

to

```
dbServerConnection.query(queryString, Object.values(query), (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(results[0]);
        }
      });
```

?